# Spigot Plugin - Cannot Build 1.10

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I have created a Spigot plugin in 1.10. It is mostly essentials but I added in a compass inventory GUI and you receive it when you first log in. For some odd reason after  I implemented this you cannot obtain items in your inventory, they instantly go away. The class for the GUI is below

```
package me.Roofah.Essentials;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Essentials extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

        this.getCommand("teleport").setExecutor(new Teleport(this));;
        this.getCommand("vanish").setExecutor(new Vanish(this));;
        this.getCommand("unvanish").setExecutor(new Vanish(this));;


        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Teleport Plugin Enabled!");
    }

        public Player getPlayer(String name) {
            for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                if(p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                    return p;
            }
            return null;

    }

    public void onDisable() {

        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Teleport Plugin Disabled!");

    }

    private void teleportInWord(Player player, int x, int y, int z) {
        player.teleport(new Location(player.getWorld(), x, y, z));
    }

    private void openGUI(Player player) {
        Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Warp Selector || By Roofah");

        ItemStack Spawn = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_AXE);
        ItemMeta SpawnMeta = Spawn.getItemMeta();
        ItemStack Build = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_PICKAXE);
        ItemMeta BuildMeta = Build.getItemMeta();

        SpawnMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Spawn");
        Spawn.setItemMeta(SpawnMeta);

        BuildMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GREEN + "Build");
        Build.setItemMeta(BuildMeta);

        // 35
        inv.setItem(3, Spawn);
        inv.setItem(5, Build);

        player.openInventory(inv);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
        if (ChatColor.stripColor(event.getInventory().getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("Warp Selector")) {
            return;
        }
        Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
        event.setCancelled(true);

        if (event.getCurrentItem() == null || event.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.AIR
                || !event.getCurrentItem().hasItemMeta()) {
            player.closeInventory();
            return;
        }

        switch(event.getCurrentItem().getType()){
        case DIAMOND_AXE:
            teleportInWord(player, 967, 90, 484);
            player.closeInventory();
            player.sendMessage(String.format("%sTeleported to %sSpawn%s!", ChatColor.GOLD, ChatColor.DARK_RED, ChatColor.GOLD));
            break;
        case DIAMOND_PICKAXE:
            teleportInWord(player, 906, 96, 428);
            player.closeInventory();
            player.sendMessage(String.format("%sTeleported to %sBUILD%s!", ChatColor.GOLD, ChatColor.GREEN, ChatColor.GOLD));
            break;

            default:
                player.closeInventory();
                break;
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerKoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        event.getPlayer().getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COMPASS));
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Action a = event.getAction();
        ItemStack is = event.getItem();
        if (a == Action.PHYSICAL || is == null || is.getType() == Material.AIR) {
            return;
        }
        if (is.getType() == Material.COMPASS) {
            openGUI(event.getPlayer());
        }

    }

}
```

There are 2 other classes but I could still obtain blocks without adding in the GUI.

Comment: You said it isn't working on 1.10. Is it Running on 1.9? And is there maybe another plugin that denies that you add an Item to the inventory?

Comment: `if (ChatColor.stripColor(event.getInventory().getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("Warp Selector")) {` seems to do the oposite of what you want (it's only doing your logic when the screen is _not_ "Warp Selector").  Maybe you want `if (!ChatColor.stripColor(event.getInventory().getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("Warp Selector")) {`?

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is a logic mistake at line 73 on your code.

You have the following:

```
 if (ChatColor.stripColor(event.getInventory().getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("Warp Selector")) //Line 73 {
        return;
    }
```

The situation is:

Whenever the inventory name is Warp Selector, return. So your code is only executing when the inventory name is not "Warp Selector".

What you probably want is to invert this logic, so that your code will execute when the inventory name is "Warp Selector".

```
if (!ChatColor.stripColor(event.getInventory().getName()).equalsIgnoreCase("Warp Selector") {
return;
}
//Code continues
```